# Aligning divs inside a container div in a two column fashion

Tags: html, css

At the moment I am trying to create a scoreboard similar to the Eurovision song contest.

So I would like to recreate the two column fashion where the countries are listed during the voting process.

So far I have succeeded in listing the inside (country) divs in a single fashion column to the left part of the container div. Any ideas how can I break the single column into two aligned columns: one on the left side of the container div and one on the right?

Code that I have tried so far is listed bellow:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: 1900px 1080px;
}
#top {
  height: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 3%;
  background-color: azure;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
#main {
  height: 80%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  background: rgba(134, 34, 87, .5);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: black;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aquamarine;
}
.img_right {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-bottom: 20px;
}
.p_right {
  margin-right: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>EUROVISION VOTING BOARD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <img class="img_right" src="assets/Albania.png">
      <p class="p_right">Albania</p>
      <p>28</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would like two columns worth of countries, where each country is left aligned and their votes are right aligned?

Comment: I would go with `ul li` here; but to answer this case, you would need to specify the exact width and height for your inner div's `.list` since `div` is block element.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the following works for you:

```css
body{
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: 1900px 1080px;
}
#top{
height: 15%;
width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 3%;
    background-color: azure;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
#main{
height: 80%;
width: 70%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
top: 20%;
background: rgba(134, 34, 87, .5);
display: flex;
flex-flow: column wrap;
justify-content: space-around;   
}

.list{ 
  display: inline-flex;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: aquamarine;  
}

.leftColumn{
  width:90%;
  float:left;
}
.rightColumn{
  width:10%;
  float:right;
}
.leftColumn img{
  float:left;
  height:18px;
}

.leftColumn p{
  margin:0px;
  font-size:15px;
}

.rightColumn p{
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>EUROVISION VOTING BOARD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="top"></div>    
<div id="main">
<div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div>   

 <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

       <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div>

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div>

       <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div>

       <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div> 

   <div class="list">
    <div class="leftColumn"><img class="img_right" src="http://www.mdgfund.org/sites/all/themes/custom/undp_2/images/flag/albania.jpg"><p class="p_right">Albania</p></div>
    <div class="rightColumn"><p>28</p></div>
</div>         
</div>

</body>
```